# OpenVPN TLS handshake failing - what ELSE could it be?

Tags: openvpn

I've got two very different clients on two very different networks, both unable to connect to a newly configured OpenVPN server, both causing log entries *on the server* like the following:

```
Aug  8 20:37:15 myserver ovpn-server[3797]: 12.34.56.78:48573 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]12.34.56.78:48573, sid=80063aef 9e45c93a
Aug  8 20:38:15 myserver ovpn-server[3797]: 12.34.56.78:48573 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Aug  8 20:38:15 myserver ovpn-server[3797]: 12.34.56.78:48573 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Aug  8 20:38:15 myserver ovpn-server[3797]: 12.34.56.78:48573 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, client-instance restarting
```

The clients are OpenVPN on a *buntu laptop computer connected to a NAT ADSL router, and a 3G/4G WWAN router with a built in OpenVPN client.

Here's what I've checked so far:

- Firewall is open (well duh, how else would TLS handshake even begin)
- Time/date is correctly set on both ends
- OpenVPN client is up to date (on the laptop at least, harder to check on the 3G/4G router)
- UDP port numbers do not change for the lifetime of the negotiation (see
  log above)

What ELSE could be causing this?

**Edit:** So, the plot thickens... In desperation I tried changing the whole chain of configs over to use TCP instead, otherwise leaving everything as it was. Bang! The OpenVPN client on my *buntu laptop was able to connect straight away. But what to do when the 3G/4G router's OpenVPN client doesn't even support TCP transport? I'm not done here yet!

**Edit:** Just to be clear here; I changed precisely *four* things to get this to work:

1. Edited OpenVPN's config to say `proto tcp` instead of `proto udp` and restarted OpenVPN
2. Added a new rule to the server's iptables firewall, to allow TCP 1194 -  otherwise identical to the already existing rule allowing UDP 1194
3. Edited the protocol on the service definition on the firewall rule in the router my laptop is connected to allow TCP 1194 outbound instead of UDP 1194 outbound (just a drop-down box really)
4. Edited the OpenVPN connection information on my laptop via Network Manager and checked the `Use a TCP connection` checkbox

*Every* other setting and configuration remains *identical* to how it was before.

**Edit:** I have a sneaky suspicion that something odd is happening with the routing of the UDP traffic on my VPN server; the IP address that OpenVPN is configured to bind to is not the primary IP address of the server, in fact it's not even on the same subnet. Here's what the routing table looks like:

```
$ route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway          Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         11-22-33-1.thing 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
22.33.44.0      *                255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
10.8.0.0        *                255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
11.22.33.0      *                255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0

$ ip route
default via 11.22.33.1 dev eth0 onlink 
22.33.44.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 22.33.44.55 
10.8.0.0/24 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.8.0.1 
11.22.33.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 11.22.33.44
```

The 22.33.44.55 IP address was assigned later, and is the one that OpenVPN binds to. Now I'm the first to admit that I know next to *nothing* about IP routing, but could it be that UDP traffic on the "new" IP address somehow gets lost due to it not having its own default route - or something?

Comment: Check your firewall again?

Comment: Double, triple, quadruple checked.

Comment: iptables rule on the VPN server: `2641  217K ACCEPT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:1194` As you can see, a fair amount of traffic, only because the 3G/4G router refuses to give up :)

Comment: Tried earlier to completely disable the firewall on the 3G/4G router but it (of course) made no difference. The router my laptop is connected to *does* block all outbound traffic, but I have set up a rule to allow 1194; before I did that I did not see *anything* on the VPN server coming from that network - for obvious reasons. TLS handshake failures for that IP address only started appearing after I allowed 1194 outbound - but this is a pretty tight case.

Comment: Is TLS enabled on the clients OpenVPN configuration ?

Comment: @ysdx: yes it is, and I did not change this when switching from UDP to TCP. See also updated question with routing/IP info - I suspect I've found the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I was kind of right: the `local 22.33.44.55` option in OpenVPN's `server.config` was missing. Adding it and restarting OpenVPN solved the issue, and UDP transport now works on my secondary IP. Without it, responses from OpenVPN were being sent via the default IP - though I don't understand why this didn't also prevent TCP from working. Schoolboy error, if you like, but the OpenSSL config script I used (https://github.com/Angristan/OpenVPN-install) *did* ask for the IP address to use during set-up, so I just assumed this had been configured correctly.

Comment: When using TCP to communicate with openvpn, the connection from the server to the client is "sticky" (it's stateful), and will come out on the same interface it came in on. UDP is not like this (it's stateless), so replies back don't have that pre-established relationship to the original source messages. You have to control the routing more strictly when using UDP, as using an asymmetric route will result in this kind of "black hole" scenario in the absence of a persistent connection between the server and its endpoints.

Comment: This fixed it for me!
Interresting observation: if my client laptop is on my phone's WiFi hotspot I need `local INTERNALSERVERIP` in the server.config . Otherwise it fails with `TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds` *after* checking the server certificate and saying it is `VERIFY OK`.
If on the other hand my client laptop is connected to the phone via "usb tethering" it can connect to the server *with and without* `local INTERNALSERVERIP` in the server.config

Answer (score 2):

Just sharing my findings while dealing with this issue. I added my xbox to the dmz a while back. While searching through the interface, I found that if the DMZ is enabled, it blocks external access to the firewall. Once I disabled the DMZ, everything worked fine. Uhg!

Comment: Thank you so much. This was the solution on a DD-WRT router.

Answer (score 0):

OpenVPN Issue - TLS key negotiation failed - Fixed

Suddenly we had these errors on our servers, for all our clients:

> Wed Jul 26 05:31:45 2023 tls-crypt unwrap error: packet too short
> Wed Jul 26 05:31:45 2023 TLS Error: tls-crypt unwrapping failed from [AF_INET]205.210.31.209:54134
> Wed Jul 26 05:52:22 2023 XX.XX.XX.XX:8532 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]185.220.10.55:8532, sid=722b49c7 300fc366
> Wed Jul 26 05:52:43 2023 XX.XX.XX.XX:36039 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]185.220.10.55:36039, sid=c3cca05e 544fb4df
> Wed Jul 26 05:52:52 2023 XX.XX.XX.XX:25800 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
> Wed Jul 26 05:52:52 2023 XX.XX.XX.XX:25800 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
> Wed Jul 26 05:52:52 2023 XX.XX.XX.XX:25800 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, client-instance restarting

After a lot of checking, we realized that the server certificate had expired.

> sudo openssl x509 -enddate -noout -in server_certificate.crt

We installed the server with the debian10-vpn.sh script which automates the configuration a lot, but the certificate it generates is valid for about 800 days.

We couldn't find a way to replace the server's certificate, so the solution we found was to uninstall and reinstall OpenVPN.

We had to regenerate the certificates of all clients again, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

> what ELSE could it be?

Well, here is a thing that affected me as well: my client was configured for UDP while the server expected TCP.

Surely not the OP's case, and probably a rookie mistake, but I guess it is good someone mentions it in the wild.