# OpenVPN server with 2 Public IP

Tags: iptables, openvpn, ip-routing

This server has 2 IP addresses as follows.

- 11.22.22.44 : primary address & exit ip address
- 11.22.33.55  : secondary address, non-exit ip address, used for
  openvpn client to connect to

i can ssh to either of the 2 IP addresses.

i want OpenVPN client connect to the server through the secondary
address and use the primary address as the exit IP to the Internet.

```
Wed Jun 24 01:33:28 2020 OpenVPN 2.4.7 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Feb 20 2019
Wed Jun 24 01:33:28 2020 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019, LZO 2.10
Wed Jun 24 01:33:28 2020 Outgoing Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Wed Jun 24 01:33:28 2020 Incoming Control Channel Authentication: Using 160 bit message hash 'SHA1' for HMAC authentication
Wed Jun 24 01:33:28 2020 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]11.22.33.55:11194
Wed Jun 24 01:33:28 2020 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->212992] S=[212992->212992]
Wed Jun 24 01:33:28 2020 UDP link local: (not bound)
Wed Jun 24 01:33:28 2020 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]11.22.33.55:11194
Wed Jun 24 01:33:28 2020 NOTE: UID/GID downgrade will be delayed because of --client, --pull, or --up-delay
Wed Jun 24 01:34:28 2020 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Wed Jun 24 01:34:28 2020 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Wed Jun 24 01:34:28 2020 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
Wed Jun 24 01:34:28 2020 Restart pause, 5 second(s)


Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         11.22.00.254   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eno1
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.2        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
11.22.33.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eno2
11.22.22.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eno1
```

ifconfig

> eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
> inet 11.22.22.44  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 11.22.22.255
> inet6 fe80::a6bf:1ff:fe25:fa37  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
> ether a4:bf:01:25:fa:37  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
> RX packets 15354  bytes 1618795 (1.5 MiB)
> RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
> TX packets 15482  bytes 2259131 (2.1 MiB)
> TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
> device memory 0xa2b00000-a2bfffff
>
> eno2: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
> inet 11.22.33.55  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 11.22.33.255
> inet6 fe80::a6bf:1ff:fe25:fa38  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
> ether a4:bf:01:25:fa:38  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
> RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
> RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
> TX packets 46  bytes 2476 (2.4 KiB)
> TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
> device memory 0xa2900000-a29fffff
>
> lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
> inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
> inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10
> loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
> RX packets 242274  bytes 13193252 (12.5 MiB)
> RX errors 0  dropped 1342  overruns 0  frame 0
> TX packets 242274  bytes 13193252 (12.5 MiB)
> TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
>
> tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
> inet 10.8.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 10.8.0.2
> inet6 fe80::1e70:64bf:9ce5:78b6  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20
> unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 100  (UNSPEC)
> RX packets 58  bytes 7715 (7.5 KiB)
> RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
> TX packets 78  bytes 20953 (20.4 KiB)
> TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

I got TLS Error after connecting to the secondary address (but worked on primary address). Is there any way to solve this (using iptables?)

Comment: Your obfuscated description is wrong: the gateway 11.22.00.254 has no route to it, even if in reality there's one. If you obfuscate, obfuscate correctly in order to keep it working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this problem was solved, just add "local 11.22.33.55" to server.conf.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your second IP isnt accessible. Can you ping 11.22.33.55 from your client ?
What does ifconfig / route show on your server?

There is a similar thread about a failed tls handshake:

[OpenVPN issue - TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds](https://serverfault.com/questions/765521/openvpn-issue-tls-key-negotiation-failed-to-occur-within-60-seconds)

Comment: Yes i can ping 11.22.33.55, also can SSH to that IP.

Comment: @PaulNemeth OP's initial description was probably flawed anyway (see my comment on the question)